# Content not fitting in IPad screen When Change in Iphone Screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

[image]Made a form in iphone 4s screen and at bottom i have submit button, when i use constraints on submit button to reside button at bottom in all screen , but when i check in IPad screen the submit button is not shown , I have to readjust the form again and bring that button bit up which look odd,i want button at bottom in all screen of iphone and ipad.How can this be achieve? [image]

Comment: it's hard to tell without knowing anything.what you have tried? edit your post with more info.

Comment: check the screen shot, submit button is coming here but i want it in bottom, when i bring it down and apply constraints , it get hide from ipad screens, which will cause problem in uplaoding my app.@DSDharma

Comment: umer plz post your constraints of submit button as image & show the screen shot in ipad too.

Comment: update your submit button top constraints with 'greater then equal to' condition instead of 'equal to'. If it is then please show your constraints.

Comment: check out my constraints .@NehaGupta

Comment: give the button bottom position as centre vertically and modify the multiplier as 1.9. Then the button's bottom will be on bottom irrespective of the size of the screen.

Comment: where is multiplier? @jegadeesh

Comment: in ipad it is coming at bottom, if we bring submit button nerar to description textview. @DSDharma

Comment: Multiplier field is shown below the priority and constant field of a constraint @umer

Comment: @umer sry for late response did you tried with bottom layout constraints for button?

Comment: in this app i have other forms inwhich i have use consraints on button and its coming to right place but the issue is coming in this page button. @DSDharma

Comment: if you wanna button at bottom make constraints like width,height,center horizontally to parent view,bottom bottom layout.remove all button constraints & try this.let me know

Answer (score 1):

Do something like below.

1. Select 4s view from storyboard
2. add dummy view 300x400
3. add your component in that dummy view textfields, submit buttons whatever you want to add in center.
4. add constraints to dummy view only
5. done

Note: any issue to view gif, download and separate frame.

[image]

Comment: I haven't get this can u elaborate? @iOS Dev

Comment: have you check GIF?  what you are not getting ?

Comment: i have use constraints and checking live preview in ipad screen also , in live preview it is showing button in the bottom of screen but when i run it its hides button from bottom .@iOS Dev

Comment: if you are using my suggested answer, then whole content will be in center.

Comment: Bro idon't want it their i have just an issue with button position . @iOS Dev